# Drawings in UIImage are being distorted

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage, core-animation, core-graphics

I have implemented a highlight function in my app. This highlight is being drawn in UIImage so that it can be saved as a PNG Representation. Everything is working perfectly but recently I realized somewhat a very confusing issue. Sometimes when I am highlighting, the drawings are being distorted. Here is what it looks like:

[image: highlight stretching to the left]

Whenever I move my finger to highlight the characters, the drawn highlights are stretching to the left. Another one:

[image: highlight fading upward]

In this one, every time I move my finger to highlight, the drawn highlights are moving upward!

This is all very confusing for me. This happens from time to time, and sometimes to certain pages only. Sometimes it works well just like this:

[image: perfect highlight]

I am very confused on why is this happening. Can anyone tell me or at least give me an idea on why is this happening? Please help me.

**THE CODE:**

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   currPoint = [[touches anyObject]locationInView:self];

   for (int r = 0; r < [rectangles count]; r++) 
   {
      CGRect rect = [[rectangles objectAtIndex:r]CGRectValue];

      //Get the edges of the rectangles
      CGFloat xEdge = rect.origin.x + rect.size.width;
      CGFloat yEdge = rect.origin.y + rect.size.height;

    if ((currPoint.x > rect.origin.x && currPoint.x < xEdge) && (currPoint.y < rect.origin.y && currPoint.y > yEdge))
    {
        imgView.image = [self drawRectsToImage:imgView.image withRectOriginX:rect.origin.x originY:rect.origin.y rectWidth:rect.size.width rectHeight:rect.size.height];
        break;
    }
   }
}

//The function that draws the highlight
- (UIImage *)drawRectsToImage:(UIImage *)image withRectOriginX:(CGFloat)x originY:(CGFloat)y rectWidth:(CGFloat)width rectHeight:(CGFloat)ht
{
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
  CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  [image drawInRect:self.bounds];

  CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, [UIColor clearColor].CGColor);

  CGRect rect = CGRectMake(x, y, width, ht);
  CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
  CGContextSetCMYKFillColor(context, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0.5);
  CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

  UIImage *ret = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
  return ret;
}
```

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's pretty hard to help you.  You need to edit your question to including the code that gets the touch coordinates and draws the highlight.

Comment: Hi. I added the code above. Please help me know what's wrong with the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you exactly why these artifacts occur, but...

I don't think it's a good idea to render an image in a touch handler. Touch handling should do as little as possible.

You might want to try using CoreAnimation's `CALayer`:

Set your image as background image like this (assuming your class is a subclass of `UIView`) or use an actual `UIImageView`:

```
self.layer.contents = (id)image.CGImage;
```

When you detect that another rectangle `rect` has been touched, add the highlight as a sublayer above your image background:

```
CALayer *highlightLayer = [CALayer layer];
highlightLayer.frame = rect;
highlightLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
highlightLayer.opacity = 0.25f;
[self.layer addSublayer:highlightLayer];
```

The `shouldRasterize` layer property may help to improve performance if necessary:

```
self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

In order do use all this, use the QuartzCore framework and import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in your implementation file.

You can create a PNG representation of your layer hierarchy by rendering the `self.layer` to an image context, then get the image and your PNG representation.

Comment: Hi Reimar. Thanks for responding. Ever since I posted this question, I switched from using the UIImage to using CALayer instead. I can say that I can finally highlight the words better. I just want to know what causes the distortion of the drawings. Anyways, thanks for your answer. I will upvote it. :)